# Calling google speech api from google cloud function on cloud storage bucket triggers

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to create a flow where i will be uploading audio file to gcp cloud storage bucket while the cloud function is triggered on this event and then that file is sent to google speech api to get translated into json response.

```
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

exports.helloGCS = (event, callback) => {

  console.log(`Processing file: ${event.data.name}`);
  // some code to get data required for speech API
  const payload = {
    audio: {
      uri: 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/quantum-fusion-205506.appspot.com/videos/${event.data.name}'
    },
    config: {
      encoding: 'FLAC',
      languageCode: 'en-US'
    }
  };

  const client = new speech.SpeechClient({
    projectId: 'quantum-fusion-205506'
  });

  client.longRunningRecognize(payload)
    .then(responses => {
      const operation = responses[0];
    console.log('Operations : ', operation);
      // current example of getting operation status by operation name with HTTP call
      request(`https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/${operation.latestResponse.name}?key=<XYZ>`, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log('Operation status response: ', body);
        console.log('Operation status response: ', error);
        console.log('Operation status response: ', response);
      });
    });
  callback();
};
```

The error returned is

```
{ insertId: "000000-94e46263-c911-4cbb-9f96-e7a0bba6945b"
  labels: {…} 
  logName: "projects/quantum-fusion-205506/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
  receiveTimestamp: "2019-03-31T19:59:43.941676738Z" 
  resource: {…} 
  severity: "ERROR" 
  textPayload: "Unhandled rejection" 
  timestamp: "2019-03-31T19:59:37.042Z" 
  trace: "projects/quantum-fusion-205506/traces/2ddeb72fed29d8b0387b0992a86e09d8" 
}
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument/
at Object.exports.createStatusError (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15) 
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1204:28) 
at InterceptingListener._callNext (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42) 
at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/@google-
cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8) 
at callback (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24)"
```

Comment: I see you have provided an application.  Does this application work?  If not, what does happen?  Is there a particular area that you are asking about?

Comment: This is my entire code on cloud function to convert the uploaded audio file from cloud storage bucket to text using speech api.... the code throws error saying that invalid arguments on calling speech api....

Comment: Can you post the full and exact nature of the error.

Comment: {
 insertId:  "000000-94e46263-c911-4cbb-9f96-e7a0bba6945b"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/quantum-fusion-205506/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-03-31T19:59:43.941676738Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "Unhandled rejection"  
 timestamp:  "2019-03-31T19:59:37.042Z"  
 trace:  "projects/quantum-fusion-205506/traces/2ddeb72fed29d8b0387b0992a86e09d8"  
}

Comment: Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1204:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/@google-

Comment: cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at callback (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24)"

Comment: I am new to cloud functions, You can suggest the correct way of calling speech api from cloud functions with triggers from storage bucket..